# Java generic issue with hibernate, how to handle T get(K id)

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

My GenericDao has:

```
 public T get(K id);
```

Now my GenericDaoImpl has:

```
public T get(K id) {
    return super.getHibernateTemplate().get(???, id);
  }
```

I tried:

```
get(T.class, id);
```

But I get a compile time error:

```
cannot select from a type variable
```

Is it possible to do this correctly somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to type erasure, that is not possible.
You need to take a `Class` instance as a parameter.

Comment: So:  T get(Class<T> type, K id) right?  Now when SomeEntityDaoImpl implements GenericDao, the get call looks 'bad' since I have to do:  get<SomeEntity>, any way to fix this?

Comment: @Blankman The compiler will infer the type parameter from the `type` argument, so the caller doesn't have to explicitly provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your GenericDao such that it will be able to figure out which concrete entity type it has been parameterized with.  For example, SomeEntityDaoImpl should be able to figure out that its entity type is SomeEntity.class.

Either

1. add an abstract method, `getEntityClass`, in GenericDao, and override that method in each DaoImpl to provide the appropriate entity class, or
2. use a reflective method to automatically look up the type parameter (I've used `MoreTypes.getGenericSupertype()` from Google Guice, followed by `ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`.)

Then you won't have to pass in the Class literal to get(), because the DaoImpl can just call getEntityClass() on its own.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

```
public abstract class DAOImpl <T, PK extends Serializable> implements DAO<T, PK>  {


  protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();

  public T findById(PK id){
    return (T)getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityClass(),id);
  }

  protected DetachedCriteria createDetachedCriteria(){
    return DetachedCriteria.forClass(getEntityClass());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<T> findAll(){
    return  getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(createDetachedCriteria());
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `GenericDaoImpl` is abstract, and all real implementation has `T` and `K` bound, then you *can* get the value of the type parameters using reflection:

```
abstract class GenericDaoImpl<K, T> {

  public T get(K id) {
    Class<?> valueClazz = (Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return super.getHibernateTemplate().get(valueClazz, id);
  }

}

class StringDao extends GenericDaoImpl<Integer, String> {
}
```

I created a slightly modified example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/YovHZ), but it just prints the type class, in this case String.

This only works in when `StringDao` (and all other DAOs) is a direct subclass of `GenericDaoImpl`, so it's a little brittle. And like I said, it will NOT work if GenericDaoImpl is not abstract but meant to be used directly. In that case I think you should consider if what you are doing is the correct approach. In my experience DAOs that are generic in that way don't really work well.